# Sudden Blender Lag

Tags: modeling, interface, workflow

I have not used Blender 2.78 in about four days. The last time I used it, it ran smoothly but when I loaded up my startup file today, everything began to lag immensely. Despite having only a cube on my screen it takes about 5 seconds for an input to register.

The worst part is I don't know what is causing the problem. I tried changing the Window Draw Method to Overlap as a recommendation but it makes no difference. It's weird because every other application I have been using works fine. How can I reduce this unexpected lag?

Answer (score 1):

Oooh, I was support to shut down Blender after changing the Window Draw Method to Overlap. Now it works fine! :)